# What is a "cool dry place" in a city apartment?

Tags: storage-method, storage

When looking at advice on storing various foods (onions, potatoes, tomatoes and more), I often read "store in a cool dry place."  They often mention a basement.

I live in an apartment in New York City. I don't have a basement. I have a countertop (not cool in summer, usually dry, not dark).  I have some cabinets, but a) They are full of dishes and such and b) Not cool and, often, not particularly dry.

I have a refrigerator. But the usual recommended temps are about 45 to 60 degrees F (c. 5 to 15 C). The frig is much colder than that.

I've considered getting a small frig for beer and wine - would that do double duty?

Comment: For how long are you planning on storing these onions / potatoes / tomatoes?

Comment: Onions and potatoes - maybe a week.  Tomatoes - less time, once they ripen, I'll eat them.  But the same advice is given for LOTS of foods.

Comment: It really depends a lot on the particular food.  I generally keep tomatoes in the veggie drawer of the fridge, but potatoes and onions can sit out on the counter or a week or two (and I live in a place where the inside temperature often goes over 80°F in the summer).  A "cool, dry place" is, as you note, generally some place between 45°F and 60°F (so not a fridge), with low humidity.  But how far you can vary from this is very dependent on the thing you are trying to preserve, and the period of time over which you expect it to remain good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a potato or [vegtable bin](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=vegetable%20bin&form=HDRSC4&first=1). There are numerous varieties, including ones similar to a trash can, large crates or cabinets with doors for each section, and stackable plastic tubs with one side cut out for easy access.